# SSO Vue.js and Java

Tags: java, vue.js, backend, single-sign-on

I would appreciate any guidance you can provide for the following situation:
I have a Vue.js app with a Java-SpringBoot backend.

I want to allow users to log in using the SSO of office-365.
So authentication will be done by office-365.
However, once a user is authenticated, the permissions are set by the application itself. All permissions for different aspects of the applications are stored and handled by my application.

How can I achieve this? Is the SSO done only on the front side in Vue.js?
If so, what is returned after the SSO completes successfully and the user is authenticated? How can I set the permissions?
Do I need to perform some backend operation to ensure the user is authenticated correctly?

Thanks

any information and explanations I can get would be apricated as I'm new to SSO

Answer (score 0):

I would use Keycloak. There you can choose Microsoft as an Identity provider. It manages everything for you and it's very easy to handle.
If you need a good tutorial: